# iPad & iPhone html placeholders stop working with iOS 6.1 update

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, ios6

ios 6.1 update seems to have stopped html placeholder's working on the iPad and iPhone.

Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: @mattytommo any info on where you get that from?

Comment: This seems like a bit of a discussion question – there's not an answer. Maybe you could rephrase as an answerable question, such as "How can I use HTML6 placeholders on iOS 6.1". It'll likely be closed by a moderator in its current state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround I detect the user agent then display a label rather than relying on the placeholder text.